# We are having a stop over for a little less than 24hours in Mumbai, do we need a visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, india, australian-citizens

We will be flying with Jet Airways from Nairobi to Mumbai to Singapore and then Melbourne. Our flight stops in Mumbai for 23hrs 45mins. We are an Australian family with young children so don't want to spend that time in an airport lounge.

Will we need a tourist or transit visa to be able to go to a hotel or see the city?

Our flight is due to arrive and depart from terminal 2 of Mumbai/Bombay.

Comment: I'd suggest staying in the terminal - Mumbai is **quite** crowded and I'd seriously not want to have you potentially run the risk of losing your children (if you have a lot). New revamps to Terminal 2 have transformed the whole departures lounge into a [really great art gallery](http://www.indianphotographer.in/2014/01/art-gallery-t2-mumbai-airport-terminal/) that I think your children would really like. If you guys need rest, I think there's a quiet area in the terminal (the old Terminal 2 had one, not sure about the new one).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, visitors (and transit passengers) from [nearly all countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_India) require a visa to enter India.

Recently (27 November 2014), India implemented ETA procedures, which allow citizens of over 40 countries including Australia, to apply for a tourist visa online. See the Indian government site [Tourist Visa on Arrival](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html) for more details and online application forms.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're just staying in the terminal, you don't need a visa - you just go through security and straight into the departures lounge. (Info for others coming across this answer)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi  23hrs 45mins in the departure lounge with young children, you are asking for trouble.

Comment: @DumbCoder That's a general comment. Even those with shorter layovers may stumble upon this question anyway.

Comment: @DumbCoder Also read my comment on the question - IMO, it's actually *better* to stay in the terminal because in Mumbai specifically, if you get out, you'll get into even *more* trouble with children.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - Not necessarily that all people will get into trouble with children. You should make it clear it in your comment that it is more relevant for short stay in terminals and not for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a visa to get out of the airport.

Australians can now avail [visa on arrival in India](http://www.indiatravelforum.in/threads/visa-on-arrival-in-india.29/) but it would cost $60 per person and to make it easier for yourself you can [apply for the visa online](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/info1.jsp) and also make a payment.